# Trying to echo an echo command

Tags: windows, command-line

Instead of echoing to the other file, this echos the echo command to the console.

```
echo (echo SET scenario=%scenario% >> "%cd%\game\playsave.bat") >> "%cd%\game\saves\%save%\stats\%save%.tmp"
```

How do I get the echo command that is supposed to be written to a new file, not executed, to actually write to the specified file instead of being showing up because of the first echo command?

Comment: What are you trying to do here?  Do you want to echo the text `echo SET scenario...` to the file, or do you want to echo the _output_ from this inner `echo` command?

Comment: I want to echo "echo SET scenario=%scenario% >> "%cd%\game\playsave.bat" to the file

Comment: Is it acceptable to have quotation marks in the output from escaping?

Comment: I would hope so, because one of the folder names is two words, so it is necessary to group it correctly.

Comment: Do you need this to work on Windows or MS-DOS?

Answer (score 1):

Escape the characters and echo as normal:

```
echo "echo SET scenario=%scenario% >> \"%cd%\game\playsave.bat\"" >> "%cd%\game\saves\%save%\stats\%save%.tmp"
```

Comment: cant find specified file path, this happened after adding the quotes.

Comment: Try running it manually and see what it outputted to the file. Was this in regards to the saved tmp file or the main one?

Comment: Most likely the .tmp, as the command is intended to echo the string into the tmp file.

Comment: i posted the code in the answer below, I had to do it as an answer because it was almost 800 characters too long for a comment.